# Array intersections with repeated elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to (quickly) determine if one array contains all the elements of another array, taking into account that the arrays may have repeated elements.

Thus, I tried something like this:

```
alice = %w(a a a b)
bob = %w(a a b c d e)
alice & bob => ["a", "b"]
alice - bob => []
```

But what I would like is an operator that will let me determine that bob does not include all the elements of alice, because bob doesn't have enough "a" characters.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: All the core methods don't account for duplicates, so you'll probably have to write your own.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby and the core/std library is pretty extensive, so I wanted to see if someone had a simple answer before I go writing anything unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, I tried stuff like `alice.each { |x| bob.delete(x) { return false } }` but the first `.delete(x)` removes all the occurrences of x.  This led to looping comparisons which look really un-ruby-like, so I figured there was probably a simple operator already written.  Apparently not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alice.select{|x| alice.count(x) > bob.count(x)}
```

**Update**
Setting up a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

def subset_multivalue?(a, b)
  bb = b.clone
  a.each do |e|
    i = bb.index(e)
    if i
      bb.delete_at(i)
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end

def subset_multivalue2?(a, b)
  a.find{|x| a.count(x) > b.count(x)}
end

def subset_multivalue3?(alice, bob)
  alice_counts = alice.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }
  bob_counts = bob.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }

  alice_counts.all? do |k, v|
    bob_counts.has_key?(k) && bob_counts[k] >= v
  end
end

alice = %w(a a a b)
bob = %w(a a b c d e)

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("dave:") do
    1000000.times do
      subset_multivalue?(alice, bob)
    end
  end

  x.report("me:") do
    1000000.times do
      subset_multivalue2?(alice,bob)
    end
  end

  x.report("andrew:") do
    1000000.times do
      subset_multivalue3?(alice,bob)
    end
  end
end
```

Results:

```
       user     system      total        real
dave: 15.054000   0.000000  15.054000 ( 15.108864)
me: 11.529000   0.031000  11.560000 ( 11.689669)
andrew: 65.036000   0.047000  65.083000 ( 67.463859)
```

Comment: Wow, so simple.  But it was more than 2x slower than my version;  I tried a couple variations, it looks like `count(Array)` is just godawful slow.

Comment: Well, yours stops after the first occurrence. If that's what you want change my 'select' to 'find'.

Comment: That's the first variation I tried.  It helps, but `count(Array)` is still the culprit.

Comment: This, unfortunately, has a rather poor O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: @Dave, if the speed that much of an issue then maybe ruby is not the best language for your project. I updated to show a benchmark, mine actually does ok.

Comment: +1 for benchmarks! Btw with larger arrays of 1000 random elements each, and reducing to 1000 repetitions, the field changes quite a bit: `dave: 4.860000; pguardiario: 0.390000; andrew: 0.880000` (which leaves me much less embarrassed `:P`). The switch to `find` from `select` helped you immensely as `select` ran a user time of `180.510000`—nearly 500x slower and showing its O(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easiest to count how often each element occurs so we don't have to worry too much about keeping track of duplicates we have/haven't counted:

```
alice_counts = alice.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }
#=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>1}

bob_counts = bob.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }
#=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1, "e"=>1}
```

Then check that each key in `alice_counts` has a value equal or greater in `bob_counts`:

```
alice_counts.all? { |k, v| bob_counts[k] >= v }
#=> false
```

Comment: As someone who is learning Ruby, and who has limited experience with functional languages, I am continuously amazed at the power of the language in such a succinct amount of code. (+1)

Comment: This solution will check for exact correspondence; sort of the same as the == operator. I extended the array class with this solution (called it `aaa`). `alice.aaa bob #=> false` as expected and `bob.aaa bob #=> true` as expected. However, `bob.dup.send(:+, [bob.last]).aaa bob #=> false` when the new array still has all elements of `bob`. I duplicated bob to emphasize they are different objects. May be that I read the question wrong and this is the functionality required but I wanted to point this out.

Comment: Shockingly, if you reverse the objects in comparison, the test passes. So `bob.aaa bob.dup.send :+, [bob.last] #=> true`. Interesting

Comment: @Yasky `a = bob + [bob.last]; a.aaa(bob)` should be `false`, since `a` has *more* than `bob`, thus `bob` cannot contain all of `a`; similarly, `alice` has more than `bob` so `alice.aaa(bob)` is `false`. The way you did it the method name should be something like `a.subset_of?(b)`.

Comment: Isn't `bob_counts.has_key?(k)` check superfluous? `bob_counts[k]` where `k` is not a key will be `0` anyway, as you set it as a default value of `bob_counts`, and the only way `0 >= v` could be true is if `alice_counts[k] == 0`, which would also have to be a default, and so `alice_count.all?` would not `yield` it.

Comment: @Amadan It is now, but it wasn't in the first version where I wasn't using a default-valued hash. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm settling on this:

```
def subset_multivalue?(a, b)
    bb = b.clone
    a.each do |e|
            i = bb.index(e)
            if i
                    bb.delete_at(i)
            else
                    return false
            end
    end
    return true
end
```

I realize it's not very rubyish, but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable#group_by() will be a choice.

```
alice = %w(a a a b)
bob = %w(a a b c d e)
alice_group = alice.group_by{|a| a}.map{|k,v| [k ,v.length]}
#=> [["a", 3], ["b", 1]]
bob_group = bob.group_by{|a| a}.map{|k,v| [k ,v.length]}
#=> [["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["c", 1], ["d", 1], ["e", 1]]
alice_group-bob_group
#=> [["a", 3]]
bob_group-alice_group
#=>[["a", 2], ["c", 1], ["d", 1], ["e", 1]]
```